# Change color of created plane

Tags: vba, catia

I'm making script that create planes. And I want add custom color for this planes.
To achieve this I using Selection.Search method. But I get error: "Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub".

```
Sub CATMain()

Dim Part as PartDocument
Set Part = CATIA.ActiveDocument.Part 
LengthDimension = 150
Set ReferenceGeom = Part.HybridBodies.Item("Skeleton").HybridBodies.Item("2. Reference geometry")
   Part.InWorkObject = ReferenceGeom

   For i = 1 to 2
      Call AddPlane(ReferenceGeom, Part, "ZX", LengthDimension, i, i)
   Next

   For j = 1 to 2
      Call AddPlane(ReferenceGeom, Part, "YZ", LengthDimension, j, j + 2)
   Next

   For k = 1 to 2
      Call AddPlane(ReferenceGeom, Part, "XY", LengthDimension, k, k + 4)
   Next

End Sub

Sub AddPlane(PointGeomSet As HybridBody, RefPart As PartDocument, Plane As String, PlaneOffset As Real, j, n As Integers)
   PlaneName = n & ". " & PlaneNamesArr(n - 1)

   .... Code to create planes (worked good)

   Set Sel = CATIA.ActiveDocument.Selection
   Sel.Search("Name=" & PlaneName & "*,all")
   Set PlaneColor = Sel.VisProperties
   PlaneColor.SetRealColor(0, 255, 0, 0) <- Here I got an error
   Sel.Clear

End Sub
```

Or maybe there are another way to change plane color?

Comment: Either you use `Call sub( param1, param2)` or you don't use parentheses `sub param1, param2`

Comment: Yes, thank you. It helps me. But color doesn't change and now I have error when script creating second plane. Message: "The Method Search failed" at this string: "Sel.Search("Name=" & PlaneName & "*,all")". And I don't understand why.

Comment: That's a complete different problem and question. If you can't figure it out on your own you can always post a new question.

Comment: I'm already solve this problem.